# Checker python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tor

I decided to create a checker for Instagram accounts.
Please tell me how you can change the ip when you restart the browser. I have a Tor profile. That is, the ip automatically changes every 10 minutes. How can I make the ip change 1 time per minute. Is this even possible?
Maybe there is some kind of set_preference setting or how in general you can change the ip when restarting the Firefox browser with the Tor settings.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

file = open('Good2.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig').read().split('\n')
goods = open('good_acc.txt', 'a+')


def settings_browser():
    """ Настройки браузера FireFox. """
    profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Scrape\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
    # get a huge speed increase by not downloading images
    profile.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2)
    profile.update_preferences()
    return profile


def check_email():
    """ Принимает всплывающее окно куки. Чекает валидность почт, если почта валидна, то сохраняет в файл 'good_acc.txt'. """

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=settings_browser(), executable_path=r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Scrape\geckodriver.exe')

    for login in file:
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/")

        body = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pbNvD.FrS-d.gD9tr')

        for bd in body:
            if bd.find_element_by_class_name('aOOlW.bIiDR').text == 'Принять все':
                bd.find_element_by_class_name('aOOlW.bIiDR').click()
                time.sleep(7)

        authorization = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("AHCwU")
        pops = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_-rjm")

        username = login.split(":")[0]
        password = login.split(":")[1]

        for data in authorization:
            # почта логин
            data_login = data.find_element_by_name('cppEmailOrUsername')
            data_login.click()
            data_login.send_keys(username)

            time.sleep(1)

            # кнопка входа
            clock_button = data.find_element_by_class_name('sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF')
            clock_button.click()

            time.sleep(2)

            for pop in pops:
                if 'Мы отправили ссылку для восстановления' in pop.find_element_by_class_name('tA2fc').text:
                    # Почта зарегана
                    goods.write(username + ' : ' + password + '\n')
                    print('Валидный аккаунт ' + username + ' : ' + password)

                elif 'Подождите несколько минут, прежде чем пытаться снова.' in pop.find_element_by_class_name('tA2fc').text:
                    driver.quit()
                    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=settings_browser(), executable_path=r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Scrape\geckodriver.exe')
                    print('Успешная перезагрузка драйвера из-за "Подождите несколько минут, прежде чем пытаться снова."')

                elif 'feedback_required' in pop.find_element_by_class_name('tA2fc').text:
                    driver.quit()
                    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=settings_browser(), executable_path=r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Scrape\geckodriver.exe')
                    print('Успешная перезагрузка драйвера из-за "feedback_required"')
                else:
                    # Почта не зарегана
                    print(f"Не валидный аккаунт " + username)
    goods.close()


def main():
    check_email()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: if you send special command to `tor` (but on different port then `9050`) then it may change `IP` (but it may need few seconds) and you don't have to wait 10 or 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

If you set `ControlPort: 9051` (and `Passord: ...`) in config file (on Linux `/etc/tor/torrc`) then you can use even standard `socket` to send signal to `tor` to change IP.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9051))
s.send('AUTHENTICATE "your_passord"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n'.encode())
```

It needs few seconds to get new IP from `tor network`.
And after few seconds proxy should use new IP.

---

You may also use module `stem` for this (it also needs settings in `torrc`)

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate(password='your_password')
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

---

More: [Python: How to use Tor Network with requests to change IP?](https://blog.furas.pl/python-how-to-use-tor-network-with-requests-to-change-ip.html)

---

**EDIT:**

```
import socket

def main():
    # send signal to `tor` to change IP
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9051))
    s.send('AUTHENTICATE "your_passord"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n'.encode())

    # wait few seconds for new IP
    time.sleep(3)

    check_email()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please show this with my example? Where should this code be added? I do not really understand.

Comment: put it at the beginning or in `main()` - that's all. Eventually add i.e. `time.sleep(3)` to check few seconds for new IP.

Comment: "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] The connection was not established. the destination computer rejected the connection request. "
For some reason, this error comes out. I do everything as you wrote.

Comment: did you set `ControlPort: 9051` and `Password: ...` in settings? Did you restart `tor` ?

Comment: Yes. I took a screenshot from above that I added settings to the `torrc` file. Maybe the settings do not work because I use `geckodriver` to start and the `firefox browser` opens with `tor` settings? Or what is the reason that changing the IP does not work for me after restarting the browser ...

Comment: settings has nothing to do with driver. Code use socket to change settings and If it can't connect then  problem has to be in different place. Maybe you have firewall which blocks it.